# Compute camera position from multiple checkboards

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, camera-calibration

I need to compute the position of a camera (C1) in the world reference system. I have 4 checkboards on 2 sides of the room, and a second camera (C2) with known extrinsics (P) and the goal is to find the position of the first camera wrt the second one, so that I can project points from the second to the first.

If my understanding of the problem is correct, this is different from computing the position of the first camera with respect to a known 3D object (one of the checkboards) because in that case the origin of the reference system would be on the object, correct?

Assuming both C1 and C2 have known intrinsic (K) matrices, my pipeline so far looks like this:

- Find 2D keypoints on each chart in a view from C2 and assign 3D coordinates (on a reference system centered on the chart for now, so if squares are 15 cm each points will be (0,0,0), (0.15,0,0) etc.)
- Multiply these 3D coordiantes by the extrinsics of C2, projecting them into a reference system centered on C2.
- Detect 2D keypoints on each chart in a view from C1
- OpenCV SolvePnP to compute P for each chart. This gives me one P for each chart, and if I understand correctly that P are the extrinsics of C1 wrt each chart. Projecting each 3D chart on the image from C1 using its P and K works, so everything should be correct up to now.

Now, my goal is to get only 1 P for C1, and I can't figure out how. SolvePnP gives me the transformation matrices projecting the 3D points of the object to C1, but I get a different one for each object because of different reference systems?

Given P1, P2, P3, P4, knowing P_C2, knowing K1 and K2, how can I compute a P matrix that allows me to relate C1 to C2?

I have a 5th object for which I know the 3D coordinates in C2 reference system, and basically the goal would be to find a P that allows me to project the points from this object to C1 without knowing the object's 2D points on C1 and using SolvePnP. Intuitively I know there should be a way to do this, but I can't think of the transformation that would do it. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you define checkerboard object coordinates in the second camera's coordinate system (or some room coordinate system) you could conpute the camera's pose according to that system. With solvePnp you can find the checkerboard poses and with those you can transform checkerboard coordinates to world coordinate system. Just use those for the solvePnp (inverted) or calibrateCamera (fixed intrinsics) of the target camera and you are done.

Comment: @Micka thanks for your comment! When you say "With solvePnp you can find the checkerboard poses and with those you can transform checkerboard coordinates to world coordinate system", the first part is my last step, which gives me P1, P2, etc. How do you transform them to the world coordinate system? Do you have an equation for this transformation? How do you use the solvePnP (inverted) to do this?

Comment: Checkerboard local coordinates transformer with solvePnp computed transformation gives you global checkerboard coordinates. The inverted solvePnp of the target camera with global checkerboard coordinates gives you the camera extrinsics of the target camera (inverted object pose is the camera pose). Same result should be the cameraCalib of the target camera with global checkerboard coordinates (fixed camera intrinsics). There you could even use all checkerboard's global coordinates at the same time in one calib call.